# How can I get a method that has an out parameter?

Tags: c#, reflection, parameters, out

Let's assume I have two method in a class looks like this:

```
class Foo
{
    public void Convert(string s, int x){ }

    public void Convert(string s, double x) { }
}
```

If I use:

```
var method = typeof (Foo)
            .GetMethod("Convert", new[] {typeof (string), typeof (int)});
```

I'm getting the correct method.But if I change `x` and  make it an `out` parameter in first method:

```
public void Convert(string s, out int x) { }
```

Then I'm getting the second method `Convert(string s, double x)`.

[image]

I don't understand why it doesn't return the first method or at least `null` instead of the second one ? The signature of second method doesn't match with the types I provide. How can I get the correct method in second case ? Is there a way to get it directly ? I know I can get all methods then filter them based on parameter types but I think there should be a direct way of doing this and I am missing it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use the `MakeByRefType` method of the `Type`:

```
var method = typeof (Foo)
            .GetMethod("Convert", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(int).MakeByRefType() });
```

Comment: that is working,but still doesn't explain why I get the second method instead of null

Comment: Yup, I understand. This is a good question. Maybe it's because of the [Implicit Numeric Conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx)...

Comment: yeah,I figure out it now and added another answer for that :) I'm accepting this anyway you were fast and answer the actual question :)

Answer (score 1):

I figure out why it doesn't return *null*, the reason was there is an implicit conversion between **double** and **int** and that's why it was matching the second method.

When I change the parameter of second method to a type that can't be convertible to `int`, for ex. `DateTime`, I get `null`, when I try with `float` I get the same method because `int` is convertible to `float` as well.